# angular - how to test directive with isolatedScope load?

Tags: angularjs

i have a directive, with isolated scope, that when created does the following

```
if ( $routeParams.flag === 'true' ){
    $scope.callSomeFunction();
}
```

how can i test that that happens?

ideally, i would like a way to spy on `callSomeFunction` - but since this is an isolated scope, i cannot.

is there a mechanism to override generation of isolated scope?

i am fine with adding in my code

```
if ( !scope.callSomeFunction ) { 
    scope.callSomeFunction = ... 
}
```

when i define the function if the mechanism requires it.

currently we are trying to spy on `$rootScope.$new`, but not sure if this is the best way to tackle it.

Here is the entire link function (`$routeParams` is inject to directive):

```
function( scope ) {
       scope.openDialog = function(){ .... }
       if ( $routeParams.flag ){
           scope.openDialog();
       }
}
```

Here  is a plunker with my directive's code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7iK2WeXkpCsfOV0eIGfl?p=preview

The idea is to write a test that checks if given `$routeParams.flag === X` then `function Y` on scope is called.

I would like to

- spyOn method Y somehow - this is the problem. i don't have any chance to do that unless i override $new which is ugly
- mock $routeParams
- expect that spy isCalled

Comment: If the scope is injected into the directive, shouldn't you just be able to inject the scope into your test and spy on it? Or do you mean you want to test the scope?

Comment: I need to spy on it before the directive's code runs because the `$routeParams` snippet i showed above are running when directives `link` function runs. chicken and the egg..

Comment: I mean, you probably need to mock `$routeparams` and spy on `callSomeFunction`. In your directive you should just test your directive code, hard to tell what is part of what here. If `$routeparams` is set by some scope code and not by the directive, you should test just that code instead. Maybe it would be better if you posted the whole thing that you want to test.

Comment: added entire link function, I want to test the `openDialog` is called when `$routeParams.flag` is true. but I don't have a chance to spy on it.

Comment: Then mock `$routeparams` and set `$routeParams.flag` to true in your test. You don't need to actually set it for real, that's not what you want to test.

Comment: The issue is not routeParams. The issue is how to spy on "openDialog" function..

Comment: `spyOn(scope, "openDialog")` after having mocked/injected your scope.

Comment: after - is too late, since the code I am trying to test already executed.

Comment: You should post your entire code in a plunkr

Comment: @Jan added plunkr code

Comment: I meant plunkr for your test as well as the code you want to test, with Jasmine included and everything (assuming that's your testing library)

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but i'll try.

Comment: @Jan - easier to do than I thought. : http://plnkr.co/edit/7iK2WeXkpCsfOV0eIGfl?p=preview